# Split and center viewport-high background image

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a background-image and two columns of content.
The columns are 100% of viewport height and 50% of viewport width, (splitting the screen in two vertical halves). The Background image is also viewport high.

When I shift the right column further to the right, that part of the background-image moves with it, leaving a gap between the two halves.

Everything works so far, but I would like to have the background image centered on the page...

Code:

```css
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-left,
.main-right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/150/150');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-left {
  left: 0;
  background-position: left 0;
}
.main-right {
  left: 50vw;
  background-position: -50vw 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-left">
    ...left content here ...
  </div>
  <div class="main-right">
    ...right content here ...
  </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1fnncnd/)

This is how it looks now:
[image]

This is how it should look:
[image]

And this is what I want to be able to do with it:
[image]

Comment: Put the background image on your body instead of main-left

Comment: ...and how would I split it then?

Comment: Really don't understand where the issue is https://jsfiddle.net/r1fnncnd/1/ .... an screenshot of the expected output will be great

Comment: @DaniP: added Pictures for clarification

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/r1fnncnd/3/

Comment: OK. I try to spell it out exactlier (if that is a term): Think of a Paper, where you have a picture, hieght of the paper, width automatically determined, horizontally centered. Now you take a scissor and cut the paper in half. Top to bottom. In the middle. And then move the right part to the right. The whole thing will be dynamic of course - I just didnt want to overload the question.

Comment: Use 2 images. Just cut that image in half.

Comment: Thank you @pol. Thats a good solution for the problem at hand. Its just not as flexible as I would have liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Give both columns a :before pseudo-element with the same dimensions as the viewport
- set the background image of these pseudoelements to the dimensions you would in a single element (In my case: 100vh auto; center top - but cover or contain would also work).
- move the right column by half the viewport and move the right:before element back by the same amount.
- hide the overflow of the columns

Code:

```css
 
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.main-left, 
.main-right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.main-left {
  left: 0;
}

.main-right {
  left: 52vw;
}

.main-left:before {
  content: "";
  z-index:-3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/500/400');
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-right:before {
  content: "";
  z-index:-3;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50vw;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/500/400');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-left">
    ...left content here ...
  </div>
  <div class="main-right">
    ...right content here ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a way to achieve your desired effect, using only one image, but only if the image is a square.

Just use the four-value syntax of `background-position` property; to set `background-position` as `-50vh` from right for `.main-left` column, and `-50vh` from left for `.main-right` column.

```css
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-left,
.main-right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/750/750');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-left {
  left: 0;
  background-position: right -50vh top 0;
}
.main-right {
  left: 51vw;
  background-position: left -50vh top 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-left">
    ...left content here ...
  </div>
  <div class="main-right">
    ...right content here ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1fnncnd/5/).

More about [`background-position`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/) property.

Comment: Thank you 5aledmaged, that is what I was looking for - except the probability of having a square image is very low. But its a step on my way ;)